# Bad configuration option: Identityfile

Tags: linux, openssh, manjaro

my ssh config was okay and it was working fine, however recently my Github ssh connection didn't work and also I wasn't able to connect to my private server using ssh connection. When I try to ssh, I get follwing error:

```
/home/hacku/.ssh/config: line 9: Bad configuration option: Identityfile
/home/hacku/.ssh/config: line 16: Bad configuration option: Identityfile
/home/hacku/.ssh/config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options
```

And here is my config file:

```
Host github.com

User git

Port 22

Hostname github.com

IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_ssh
TCPKeepAlive yes

Host linode
    HostName serv_ip_address
    User hackU
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private_key
```

I copied exact same config file and my private key into another machine and it worked great (Termux, ssh version => OpenSSH_8.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021).

I checked my ssh package version it was OpenSSH_8.7p1, so I thought maybe the update broke it. So I downgraded it to OpenSSH_8.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021, it also didn't work, additionally I tried to restart sshd by using

`sudo systemctl restart sshd`

But none of the above worked.

I'm using manjaro gnome edition as my daily driver.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: `IdentityFile` has been a config option for a very long time, and I don't think they're planning on removing it at any point. Maybe there's a bad line ending or character in there?

Comment: I opended it with different editor and I couldnt see any illegal character there...

Comment: Maybe take a look with a hex editor and see if there's an invisible character?

Comment: I don't know but it seems like it is not character related as I have deleted and wrote config file from the scratch, but seems like it keeps giving me the same error

Comment: Okay, sorry about the red herring, I've seen random characters cause issues in SSH configs before, but it looks like that's not the case here.

Comment: No, worries I just mentioned it so that it may help to understand the root of the problem.

Comment: did you try full path to the key instead of ~ use /home/hacku/ ?

Comment: This question as a whole is off-topic here: Questions about configuring your OS's tools, vs writing software, belong over on [unix.se].

Answer (score 3):

Everything theoretically seemed okay but the thing was that it was weirdly throwing this error. After doing some reading, [I found this information here](https://superuser.com/questions/268776/how-do-i-configure-ssh-so-it-doesnt-try-all-the-identity-files-automatically):

> if you use an ssh-agent, ssh will automatically try to use the keys in the agent, even if you have not specified them with in ssh_config's IdentityFile (or -i) option. This is a common reason you might get the Too many authentication failures for user error. Using the IdentitiesOnly yes option will disable this behavior.

So I completely deleted IdentityFile option. Hence my final config file is like that and both connection works just fine.

```
Host github.com
    User git
    Port 22
    Hostname github.com
    TCPKeepAlive yes

Host linode
    HostName server_ip_address
    User hackU
    Port 22
```

However, the reason for the problem for me still is unknown. I would be glad to hear, in case someone finds it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue - couldn't ssh to any host at all.

I'd recently edited the ~/.ssh/config file and typo'd the word 'IdentityFile' in *one* host config.  It must check the entire file before attempting to connect to *any* host.

Fixed the typo and I'm back to connecting.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In the OP's case, their error message comes with line numbers, and in their sample config file those lines do not have any evident typo (unless there's something like non-unicode characters, but that's still something that can be answered vs speculated about).